# Connect a new xib to a class that inherits from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I want to create a custom `UIView` and set layout using a XIB file.

To this XIB, I have added four `UIButton`s using Interface Builder.

Now I want to connect these four buttons to my custom `UIView` class and manage there `IBActions`. **This is very important, I have to do it this way.**

To load the xib I do:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView"
                                                        owner:self
                                                      options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I also have a storyboard and I have added an `UIView` to main `ViewController` using Interface Builder.

My question is: **What do I have to do to connect the new XIB file to my custom `UIView` on Interface Builder?**

I think I have to open this new xib on Interface Builder and set main `ViewController` as File's Owner, and set my custom `UIView` class as class for the view on this new XIB, but I'm not sure.

And, on main `ViewController` change the class for this new view to my custom `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, set the custom class to your `CustomView`.Make the connections to this custom class. In the whichever view controller you want to use this xib, Simply load the nib using `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method.

```
CustomView *cView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView"
                                                    owner:nil
                                                  options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[cView.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(actnForBtn1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cView.label1 setText:@"sometext"];
[self.view addSubview:cView];
```

And do add the method `actnForBtn1:(id)sender` in your view controller to do different things in different view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In View.h

```
+(View *)loadViewFromNib;
```

In View.m

```
+(View *)loadViewFromNib{
    return (View *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:0] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

To load the View call

```
View *view = [View loadViewFromNib];
```

In your View.xib file set the **Files Owner class to View** and your **Views class to View** connect the Outlets only to the View, **not to the FilesOwner!**